# merge two non-identical pandas dataframe by using specified column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I want to merge two pandas dataframes using the column common to both. I couldn't do it because their structures are different from each other. I would be glad if you can help with this.

first dataframe df1 is something like this:

```
    eq_id           stacode mag depth stalat    stalon      epidist mag_type
0   20230206011734  0118    7.4 7.0 37.03616    35.31843    155.12  Mw
1   20230206011734  0119    7.4 7.0 36.56800    35.39000    166.72  Mw
2   20230206011734  0120    7.4 7.0 36.77006    35.79005    124.91  Mw
3   20230206011734  0122    7.4 7.0 37.43390    35.82021    109.39  Mw
4   20230206011734  0123    7.4 7.0 37.00338    35.34376    153.62  Mw
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
```

second dataframe df2 is something like this

```
    latitude    longitude   pga_sta stacode
0   35.31843    37.03616    0.226   0118
1   35.39000    36.56800    0.272   0119
2   35.79005    36.77006    0.319   0120
3   35.82021    37.43390    0.274   0122
4   35.34376    37.00338    0.231   0123
... ... ... ... ...
```

I try this but doesn't work:

```
new_df =df1.merge(df2,how='outer', left_on='stacode', right_on=['stacode',"pga_sta"])
```

I would like to obtain something like this. By considering stacode column add df2.pga_sta to df1 as a new column

| eq_id | stacode | mag | depth | stalat | stalon | epidist | mag_type | pga_sta |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20230206011734 | 0118 | 7.4 | 7.0 | 37.03616 | 35.31843 | 155.12 | Mw | 0.226 |
| 20230206011734 | 0119 | 7.4 | 7.0 | 36.56800 | 35.39000 | 166.72 | Mw | 0.272 |
| 20230206011734 | 0120 | 7.4 | 7.0 | 36.77006 | 35.79005 | 124.91 | Mw | 0.319 |
| 20230206011734 | 0122 | 7.4 | 7.0 | 37.43390 | 35.82021 | 109.39 | Mw | 0.274 |
| 20230206011734 | 0123 | 7.4 | 7.0 | 37.00338 | 35.34376 | 153.62 | Mw | 0.231 |

Thanks for your help

Comment: Why do you include "pga_sta" in the merge? Shouldn't you do: `new_df = df1.merge(df2,how='outer', on='stacode')`

Comment: I tried this but it is not solving my problem.

Comment: Then you need to better explain your problem, we currently have no idea of what you want ("*it doesn't work*" is not a problem description). Modify your example to be more clear (less columns, non-ambiguous dummy data) and provide the **exact** expected output that matches the dummy data.

Comment: Thanks you are right.  Actually I have two dataframes and both are including same column which is named stacode. Second dataframe including stacode and pga_sta columns and first dataframe is also including stacode column. By considering these two dataframes by using stacode column, add pga_sta value to first dataframe as a new column. something left join in SQL statement. But I would like to do this only using pandas dataframe. Before asking here, believe me, I visited many question and answer sites on the internet, but I could not find a solution.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to improve clarity. In its current state it should probably be closed